# EJB interceptor with logging and nested EJB calls

Tags: java, logging, ejb-3.0, interceptor, mdc

I'm trying to apply general logging for EJB calls via an interceptor. This logging should log the security principal for a bean. The approach uses MDC and pushes the principal to the MDC and removes it, when the method call is finished.

However this approach fails, when a EJB method call is made within an EJB. See the demo code below. Is there any solution or a better aproach that tackles this problem?

```
public class LoggingInterceptor {

    @Resource
    protected SessionContext sessionCtx;

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object intercept(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {
        Principal principal = sessionCtx.getCallerPrincipal();
        if (principal != null) {
            MDC.put("USER_KEY", principal.getName());
        }
        try {
            return ctx.proceed();
        } finally {
            MDC.remove("USER_KEY");
        }
    }
}
```

Now I try to use this with session beans as follows:

```
@Stateless
@Interceptors(LoggingInterceptor.class)
public class Bean1 {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Bean1.class);

    @Resource
    Bean2 bean2;

    public String doSomething() {
        logger.debug("Step1.");
        bean2.doMore();
        logger.debug("Step2.");
```

and bean 2:

```
@Stateless
@Interceptors(LoggingInterceptor.class)
public class Bean2 {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Bean2.class);

    public String doMore() {
        logger.debug("Step in Bean2.");
```

When Bean2 is called directly the logging works:

```
23:53:00,093 DEBUG [Bean2] [testuser] Step in Bean2.
```

However when calling Bean1 the second log statement doesn't have the user anymore, as the UserKey has been removed from the MDC by the finally-Block of the Interception of Bean2:

```
23:53:00,093 DEBUG [Bean1] [testuser] Step1.
23:53:00,193 DEBUG [Bean2] [testuser] Step in Bean2.
23:53:00,293 DEBUG [Bean1] [] Step2.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the previous principal name before proceeding in the interceptor.

```
@AroundInvoke
public Object intercept(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {
    Principal principal = sessionCtx.getCallerPrincipal();
    String previousPrincipalName = MDC.get("USER_KEY");

    MDC.put("USER_KEY", principal == null ? "" : principal.getName());

    try {
        return ctx.proceed();
    } finally {
        MDC.put("USER_KEY", previousPrincipalName);
    }
}
```

Comment: But with this proposal I will never remove the user in the MDC.

Comment: Is that important? If there was no user before invocation of a method, then after the invocation USER_KEY in MDC will be equal to null. Naturally the code can be enhanced so that it is removed from the map, but the idea stays the same.